# Searching through HTML table with jQuery loaded data

Tags: jquery, html, search, html-table, filtering

```
<table id="gridtable"> 
            <thead>
                <tr align="left">
                    <th style="width: 50%;">Sup</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%;">Rating</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;">Number</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here's the HTML table.
tbody is filled with data from a .json file.

I am looking for a solution where I can filter the table by a searching for a specific word and/or by rating which is chosen from a dropdown menu.

```
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="GET">
            <fieldset class="clearfix">
                <input type="search" name="search" value="Search" onFocus="if(this.value=='Search suppliers')this.value=''" />
                <select name="mydropdown">
                    <option selected="selected">Select rating</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

I am absolutely clueless and would be eternally grateful for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-jquery-to-manipulate-and-filter-data--net-5351).

Comment: I am deeply sorry. I also forgot to mention that I do in fact need this to work with a search button and not as a live search.